# A book on solved Probability problems

Tags: probability, self-study, references

I was looking for a book to practice Probability problems with solutions to get intuition of Probability and I see Schaum's series is kind of most respected on solved problems.  But I wonder which on is good out of so many [Schaum'e Series on Probability](https://amzn.to/2Pm9Z5d)

Comment: It is probably (pun intended) heretical to say on stats.SE that if your goal is to learn _probability_, you should avoid any book with "Statistics" or "Probability and Statistics" in its title; stick with "Probability" alone, preferably without qualifiers such as "for engineers and scientists" or "econometrics and finance".  That being said, I have always been partial to Hsu's "Probability, Random Variables, and Random Processes" in the Schaum's Outline Series.

Comment: Graduate level: https://www.amazon.com/Exercises-Probability-Grimmett-Stirzaker-Publisher/dp/B00BG70UDS

Comment: https://researchportal.hw.ac.uk/en/publications/problems-and-exercises-in-probability-theory Problems and exercises in probability theory
Serguei Foss, D. Korshunov, I. Asymont

Answer (score 2):

Mosteller's *Fifty Challenging Problems in Probability with Solutions* though it's more recreational type problems than exercises.

Answer (score 1):

An Introduction to Probability Theory and its Applications Volume 1 by William Feller
http://libgen.io/search.php?req=feller+volume+1&lg_topic=libgen&open=0&view=simple&res=25&phrase=1&column=def